# Encrypted ID in URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to hash or encrypt a record's ID for URLs such that people can't view various records simply by guessing different integer IDs.

Essentially, my URLs would be something like this: /plans/0AUTxwoGkOYfiZGd2
instead of /plans/304.

Would the best way to do this just be to use SHA-1 to hash the plan's id and store it in a hashed_id column for plans? Then, overwrite to_param and add a finder to find by hashed_id?

How do you ensure that the characters generated are 0-9, a-z, or A-Z?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to add a salt to the hashed ID if you go this route; otherwise people will just be able to guess the encrypted values for small integers.

Answer (score 2):

> *How do you ensure that the characters generated are 0-9, a-z, or A-Z?*

```
idForURL = URI.escape((Base64.encode64(hash).strip))
```

I once [encrypted the id with Blowfish](http://alicebobandmallory.com/articles/2007/11/15/blowfish-in-the-url), it's not super safe but it's kind of convenient and the id gets shorter than for a [GUID](http://rubyforge.org/projects/uuidtools/) or a SHA-1.

```
require 'digest/sha1'
print Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("Let's see how long this gets.")
=> b26316a2db52609f86b540de65282b9d367e085c
```

Answer (score 2):

i use 
https://github.com/norman/friendly_id this way:

```
  # app/models/secret.rb; this would go in the model you want to obfuscate
  class Secret < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_friendly_id :code, :use_slug => true

    validates :name, :uniqueness => true

    def code
       Digest::SHA1.hexdigest self.name
    end
  end
```

it’s simple. If your security needs are serious you’d probably want something a little more complex (not to mention more layered than a basic obfuscation technique), but I wanted to share an out-of-the-box way to use a gem that already exists (and may even be in use in your app already)

Answer (score 1):

Include in your model a random code creator, than refer FriendlyId to it.

```rb
class Restaurant < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :random_code, use: :slugged

  def random_code
    SecureRandom.hex(10) #=> "92b15d6c8dc4beb5f559"
  end
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 1):

I think previous answers help in the encryption part, but no one adresses the first part of the question:

*...such that people can't view various records simply by guessing different integer IDs*

As Matt Rohrer answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70706005/16903898) to be able to access the resource only through the encrypted ID you could use friendly_id this way:

models/plan.rb

```
class Plan < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :hashed_id #hashed_id is already a plan column

  validates :hashed_id, uniqueness: true
  before_create :generate_hash

  def generate_hash
    # This way you ensure the hash contains letters or numbers but is not very secure
    all_letters = [('A'..'Z'), ('a'..'z'), ('0'..'9')].map(&:to_a).flatten
    random_string = (0...8).map { all_letters[rand(36)] }.join
    self.hashed_id = random_string
  end
```

controllers/plans_controller.rb

```
class PlansController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_plan, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
...
  private
    def set_plan
      # This allows accessibility to plans only through hashed_id
      @plan = Plan.find_by!(hashed_id: params[:id])
    end
  end
```

If you want a more secure encryption you should use SecureRandom or digest/sha1, maybe [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614780/completely-random-identifier-of-a-given-length) examples can help.